# Adding React app to an existing dot net core Razor Pages application

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a dot net core Razor Pages application and this applications its own package.json.

I ran npx create-react-app which created the react folder at the same level as the website.

How would I compile and build the react app so that I can add the react app to my Razor pages?

This is my project structure

[image]

How can I build my react app and add a react app to my website?